# Tailwind grid - centered new line items

Tags: tailwind-css

I wonder how to center grid items that break into the new row.

I'm trying to get my grid elements organized like this:
[image]

This is my current code:

```
.items-body {
    @apply grid gap-10 grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4;
}
```

Items count is dynamic, there could be single or several items. I would like to have those items, breaking into the new line, centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using `flex`, `flex-wrap`, `justify-center`

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-2">
  <div class="h-40 w-40 bg-purple-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-40 bg-purple-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-40 bg-purple-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-40 bg-purple-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-40 bg-purple-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-40 bg-purple-200"></div>
</div>
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by adding `col-start-2` and `col-start-3` to adjust the last two `<div>` in the center.

```
<div class="container mx-10 my-10 grid grid-cols-4 gap-2
   md:grid-rows-6 lg:grid-flow-col lg:grid-rows-2">
<div class="rounded-md border-[1px] border-purple-600 bg- 
   purple-500 px-10 py-5">1st</div>
<div class="rounded-md border-[1px] border-purple-600 bg- 
   purple-500 px-10 py-5">2nd</div>
<div class="rounded-md border-[1px] border-purple-600 bg- 
   purple-500 px-10 py-5">3rd</div>
<div class="rounded-md border-[1px] border-purple-600 bg- 
   purple-500 px-10 py-5">4th</div>

<div class="col-start-2 rounded-md border-[1px] border- 
   purple-600 bg-purple-500 px-10 py-5">5th</div>
<div class="col-start-3 rounded-md border-[1px] border- 
   purple-600 bg-purple-500 px-10 py-5">6th</div>
</div>
```

Here's the live demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZvJepE9epK